# Pronunciation of "因为"

Tags: pronunciation

*因为* is usually pronounced as *yīn wèi*, but sometimes I hear it pronounced as *yīn wéi* which really brings out the meaning as *reason (yīn) being (wéi)*.

Which pronunciation came about first? Do regional differences account for this phenomenon? Are the two completely interchangeable in meaning?

Comment: They are 99.9% the same, just like "increase" in English. You can read it as in'crease or 'increase. Luckily in cantonese there is only one pronunciation: jan1 wai6 (yan wai).

Comment: Actually, I think 'increase is a noun, while in'crease is a verb. There are many examples of noun-verb pairs distinguished by stress. Another one is record.

Comment: Just FWIW: according to the Pleco dictionary, there is an alternative pronunciation: yin1wei5. More precisely, the Pleco dictionary gives: yin1wei4/yin1wei5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't have believed you unless I checked it myself, but it appears these are both interchangeable with one source claiming:

http://www.askbennychinese.com/questions/detail/3713

> In fact, in the south of China, people says “yīn wèi”, while in the
>   north people say “yīn wéi”. The only difference lies in the
>   pronunciation. Basically, they are exactly the same.

My wife and most of my friends are from the South which is maybe why I have always heard it as yīn wèi.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%9B%A0%E4%B8%BA says:

> 因为 (simplified, Pinyin yīnwèi or yīnwéi, traditional 因為)

Comment: I'm not arguing about your answer, just for your information: in Modern Chinese Dictionary(1996, a bit old ...), the pronunciation is listed as 'yīn wei' (neutral) or 'yīn wèi'.

Comment: +1 I learned it as yin1wei4, but the fact that different pronunciations exist does not surprise me.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, yīnwèi is a modern Chinese WORD, and yīnwéi is a PHRASE from classical Chinese.
Technically, you should always pronounce yīnwèi for you are speaking modern Chinese, but actually, you can pronounce what you like, nobody treated yīnwéi as a phrase unless they are dealing with classical Chinese.

Comment: a good example is 倒因為果 ( dào yīn wéi guǒ )

Answer (score 2):

This online dictionary with pronunciations will help you.
http://xh.5156edu.com/html3/1751.html

General speaking, we use the second pronunciation when it is a verb.

为 
（爲） 
wéi
◎ 做，行，做事：～人。～时。～难。不～己甚（不做得太过分）。 
◎ 当做，认做：以～。认～。习以～常。 
◎ 变成：成～。 
◎ 是：十两～一斤。 
◎ 治理，处理：～政。 
◎ 被：～天下笑。 
◎ 表示强调：大～恼火。 
◎ 助词，表示反诘或感叹：敌未灭，何以家～？ 
◎ 姓。

为 
（爲） 
wèi 
替，给：为民请命。为虎作伥。为国捐躯。 
表目的：为了。为何。 
对，向：不足为外人道。 
帮助，卫护。

笔画数：4； 
部首：丶； 
笔顺编号：4354

Comment: I never heard any ordinary Chinese speak 因为 as yīnwèi.

Comment: Go to the south. All the 南方人 I know say yin1wei4, and no one says yin1wei2.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question to someone a while ago the answer was:

为(wéi) would be how you prounance it for 选为 (Selected to be/ellected) were 为(wéi) means to be or to become

为(wèi) would be how you prounance it for 因为 (Becuase / Reason Being) were 为(wèi) means being or becuase of

Note: no-native speaker take what I have learnt with a grain of salt

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you say yīn wéi because it sounds more standard (Mandarin) to me. No reason, just the feeling.

Comment: No, yīn wéi is not correct, or at least is not standard. See http://www.zdic.net/cd/ci/6/ZdicE5Zdic9BZdicA0102058.htm

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's incorrect according to many authority sources. I even did not notice this before! But I heard much more yīn wéi than yīn wèi. That's interesting :)

Comment: Maybe they are affected by their dialects.

Answer (score 0):

It should be yīnwèi. See [Zdic](http://www.zdic.net/cd/ci/6/ZdicE5Zdic9BZdicA0102058.htm). yīnwéi may be from some dialects and is not standard.